# Cannot write arobase in a Button?

Tags: android, xml, symbols, at-command

I just want to create a button ion Android that will link to my Twitter account:

```
    <Button style="@style/HomeButton"
        android:text="@waza_be" android:drawableTop="@drawable/home_btn_twit_default"
        android:onClick="onTwitClick" />
```

But unfortunately, I got an error just because my text start with arobase!

> error: Error: No resource type
>   specified (at 'text' with value
>   '@waza_be').

If I remove "@", everything works fine.

What can I do?

Comment: did you try android:text="\@waza_be"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
android:text="\@waza_be"
```

or

```
android:text="\\@waza_be"
```

one of them should work.

Answer (score 0):

Store it in strings.xml then load it as `android:text="@string/variablename"`

or programmicaly

```
button.setText(R.string.variablename);
```